# ffmpeg stream Attachment: ttf causes error

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to convert a mkv file to a mp4 file with h265 encoding. I want to keep all streams. I tried it with `ffmpeg -i INPUT.mkv -map 0 -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -c:s mov_text "compressed/OUTPUT.mp4"

```
ffmpeg version n5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (GCC)
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'INPUT.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.4.2 + libmatroska v1.6.4
    creation_time   : 2022-09-18T14:50:32.000000Z
  Duration: 00:23:39.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 20636 kb/s
  Chapters:
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 59.059000
      Metadata:
        title           : Prologue
    Chapter #0:1: start 59.059000, end 437.562000
      Metadata:
        title           : Part A

  Stream #0:5: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : AveriaLibre-Bold.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
File 'compressed/OUTPUT.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (flac (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (flac (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (ass (ssa) -> mov_text (native))
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:4 (ass (ssa) -> mov_text (native))
  Stream #0:5 -> #0:5 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.5
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 11.2.0][64 bit] 10bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
x265 [info]: Main 10 profile, Level-4 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 12 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 3 / wpp(17 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 3
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias  : 23 / 250 / 40 / 5.00 
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / off / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : CRF-28.0 / 0.60
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 early-skip rskip mode=1 signhide tmvp
x265 [info]: tools: b-intra strong-intra-smoothing lslices=6 deblock sao
[mp4 @ 0x5630bcf8aa00] Could not find tag for codec ttf in stream #5, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
```

Comment: Just to check, can you try with a MKV output file? If it works it means that ffmpeg knows about the ttf type, but the type is not supported in MP4 files. If it doesn't work then it means the ffmpeg doesn't know the ttf type itself.

Comment: if i do that i run into that error `matroska @ 0x561c0914fd00] Subtitle codec 94213 is not supported`

Comment: I'm not sure if `mov_text` is supported in MKV containers. Just put `-c:s copy` instead.

Comment: it works when i just copy the subtitles

Comment: So, it's just that the MP4 container cannot embed a ttf type. Do you need MP4, or is MKV OK for you?

Comment: i need a mp4. the ttf is a part of the subtitles.

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to force ffmpeg to write non-standard streams. Maybe try adding `-strict experimental`, but it doubt it can do... Maybe other tools would do, give a try with Handbrake. Why do you absolutely need a MP4 file?